# How to execute python code from within a python method?

Tags: python, deployment, continuous-integration

I'm writing a deployment engine for our code.

I plan to put a "deploy.py" in each project directory and then decide what projects need to be deployed, having the "deploy.py" of each project execute his logic for proper deployment configuration.

How would you recommend doing this? I've been thinking about "executing" the python code in each deploy.py file from within the "deployment_engine.py" code (I got this idea from scons method of doing stuff).

Alternativly I would like to somehow "import" the code (note that under each project the file is named "deploy.py" so a simple import `deploy.py` doesn't seem to do the job here)

Thank you,
Maxim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`__import__` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) to do dynamic imports.

Comment: ... and make a `main` function which does everything needed and put that function call at the top-level or in `if __name__ == 'deploy': main()`

Comment: That sound's like a excellent solution. Could someone please provide a code sample? I'm new to python...

Comment: @Maxim Veksler: There's examples in the online docs for `__import__` function in the link included with this answer -- what more do you want?